# WooCommerce main product image

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to make a simple change to WooCommerce default template. Currently, the gallery displays on the left side just under the main image. I want it to display on the right side just under the short blurb  description. I managed to do this by adding the following code to the functions.php file:

```
/*Relocate Product Gallery*/

remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce-main-image', 20 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 100 );
```

The first line removes the group of images (main and gallery) from the left side.
The last line puts just the gallery exactly where I want it. 
The middle line is the issue. I want just the main product image to appear where it should, but instead it's throwing an error. Am I using the wrong vaiable name to call just the main product image?

Comment: What error is it throwing? I also noticed your function callback is user hyphens; I imagine it should be `woocommerce_main_image`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I changed the hyphens for underscores, but same result.
Below is the screen capture for the entire error message.


[screen cap of error][1]


  [1]: http://webauthorings.com/stack/php_error.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you! Accomplished.

```
/*---Move Product Gallery*/

remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 20  );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 100 );
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that there is no function called `woocommerce_main_image` -  you should be using [`woocommerce_show_product_images`](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_show_product_images.html) instead. If you check `wc-template-hooks.php` you'll see that it's hooked by default:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
```

What's not clear is why it's not already showing - perhaps your template isn't calling the `woocommerce_before_single_product_summary` action.

---

You say you want to display the main image separately from the thumbnails; I'm going to give you the long-winded explanation as to how it all works so that you have a better understanding: 
Have a peek at `wc-template-functions.php` - you'll find that the `woocommerce_show_product_images()` includes the `product-image.php` file via this line:

```
// wc-template-functions.php:716
wc_get_template( 'single-product/product-image.php' ); // Includes product-image.php
```

This displays the main image *and* has a hook for displaying the thumbnails:

```
// product-image.php:43
do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' ); // woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails() is hooked to this
```

You can either [create your own copy of `product-image.php` to override and remove the `do_action()`](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) OR you can unhook the function that is actually displaying the thumbnails using `remove_action()`. If you look in `wc-template-hooks.php` again you'll see:

```
// wc-template-hooks.php:108
// This hooks the function to the action
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 20 );
```

That's what's hooking in the function to the action. You can remove this by putting...

```
// This unhooks the function from the action
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails' );
```

... into your theme `functions.php` file. To display the thumbnails in a different location you can simply use either the `woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails()` function or `wc_get_template( 'single-product/product-thumbnails.php' )` in your template; the former is simply a wrapper function for the latter.

Hopefully that's a clear enough explanation for you to figure the rest out. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Dre, Thank you for your reply. Problem with 'woocommerce_show_product_images' is that it also brings up the row of gallery thumbnails. Goal is to split the images so that thumbnails show under blurb on right and main single product image shows on left. There doesn't seem to be a single variable name for just the large single image.

Comment: I expanded on my answer above; the issue you have is that there *is* a function for displaying the main image, but that then goes on to run another function that displays the thumbnails. My answer above explains how you would go about unhooking these two functions from each other so that you can run them both independently.